# Pattern doesn't match

Tags: regex, fluentd

I have simple fluentd conf:

```
<source>
  @type tail
  @id in_tail_springboot_container_logs
  #path /var/log/containers/*.log
  path /var/log/logtest.txt
  #path /var/log/containers/springbootrabbitmqlistener-*.log
  pos_file /var/log/fluentd-springboot-containers.log.pos
  @log_level debug
  multiline_flush_interval 5s
  format multiline
  format1 (?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})  (?<level>INFO|ERROR|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG|FATAL)\s+\[(?<app>[^\,]+),(?<zipkintraceid>[^\,]*),(?<zipkinspanid>[^\,]*),(?<zipkinsent>[^\]]*)] (?<someid>[0-9]+) --- \[(?<thread>[^\]]+)] (?<classname>[^\ ]+)\s+\: (?<text>.*)
  format_firstline ?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}
  tag springboot.*
  read_from_head true
  <parse>
    @type json
    time_format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%NZ
  </parse>
</source>
```

I test it with input line:

```
2018-11-09 08:49:36.111  INFO [SpringBootMicroservice,,,] 5820 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
```

I've tested it with https://regex101.com/.

Everything works fine.

Problem is that fluent doesn't like it:

```
2018-11-09 08:48:18 +0000 [warn]: #0 [in_tail_springboot_container_logs] pattern not match: "2018-11-09 08:49:36.111  INFO [SpringBootMicroservice,id1,id2,true] 5820 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'environmentManager' has been autodetected for JMX exposure"
```

Can you tell me what is wrong with my conf?

Comment: First, escape the `.` that should match a real dot. Also, check `format_firstline ?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}` - you seem to have lost the parentheses.

Comment: Try `format /^(?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})\s+(?<level>INFO|ERROR|WARN|TRACE|DEBUG|FATAL)\s+\[(?<app>[^,]+),(?<zipkintraceid>[^,]*),(?<zipkinspanid>[^,]*),(?<zipkinsent>[^\]]*)]\s+(?<someid>[0-9]+) ---\s*\[(?<thread>[^\]]+)]\s*(?<classname>\S+)\s*:\s*(?<text>.*)$/` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/WIOtCc/1)).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the problem is with this line:

```
format_firstline ?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3}
```

The issue is that the timestamp named group is incorrectly formatted - It needs parenthesis around the entire group, like so:

```
                 ↓                                                      ↓
format_firstline (?<timestamp>\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3})
                                                                 ↑
```

And for good practice, (as the Regex veteran Wiktor mentioned) you should escape your `.`'s when they are meant to be literal dot's, not wildcards.